# Git submodules for syntax files

Tags: syntax-highlighting, git

I keep my VIM folder under git version control. I use git submodules and Pathogen to keep my VIM plugins updated. The folder structure is .vim/bundle/$PLUGIN

Is it possible to use git submodules for syntax files? With plugins this works because each plugin corresponds to the submodule repository in its own folder. As far as I can tell syntax files cannot be in sub-folders (arising from the cloned git submodule repository) within .vim/syntax  and this approach breaks down.

Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: I would consider syntax files not shipped with Vim (which are not minor adjustments kept in an `after` directory) to be syntax plugins. You should be able to load them the way you do other plugins. Are you using Pathogen?

Comment: Oops, yes, I meant pathogen when I wrote bundle. Can you elaborate on "You should be able to load them the way you do other plugins."? Thanks!

Comment: This vim (syntax) plugin has a pathogen installation example: https://github.com/octol/vim-cpp-enhanced-highlight - so you basically install it similar to other plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugin managers like Pathogen add each subdirectory of `.vim/bundle/` to the `'runtimepath'`. If a syntax plugin has the proper `syntax/foo.vim` (or `after/syntax/foo.vim`) structure in its repository, it will work just like regular plugins (which need to use the `plugin/` and `autoload/` subdirs).

You can use the `:scriptnames` command to see what Vim actually loaded, and check the runtimepath via `:set rtp?`

Comment: Thanks, this works! Unfortunately my score is too low to up-vote as well.